# Execution of the command of ssh with open/root/.ssh/id_dsa failed error: Permission denied

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, solaris

Working it agrees http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-hadoop-1/ at first I entered into the user of hadoop by means of a command

```
root@one: /volumes# su hadoop
```

The invitation was as a result displayed

```
root@one: /volumes#
```

and to check I entered into the user of `hadoop` executed the `whoami` command, on what gave out me `hadoop`. Then I tried to execute

```
root@one: /volumes# ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

therefore I received the following messages

```
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
open /root/.ssh/id_dsa failed: Permission denied.
Saving the key failed: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Нow to eliminate this error?

Comment: Does that file already exist? If so, are you able to `rm` it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change path to your home directory that is

```
root@one: /volumes# cd ~
```

then generate the dsa key using the below command and press enter for the inputs(passphrase) when asked.

```
root@one: ~# ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

Now the file and directory containing the key will be created.

> ~/.ssh/id_dsa

Answer (score 0):

You are running as user `hadoop`, but the home directory still seems to be `/root`.

Try `su -l hadoop` instead to do a complete login.

Answer (score -2):

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh --recursive
```

will do the job

Comment: And what the option `--recursive` does and what for the rights the command `chmod 700 ~/.ssh --recursive` provides @specializt (I am a beginner in `linux`)?

Comment: ... what?
Im assuming you have problems writing in english, furthermore, im assuming you were asking about the parameters - well :
700 gives only root access (nobody else, which is good) and --recursive makes chmod iterate over _everything_ in that directory